# Is (or was) the exclamation "Nuts!" crude?

Tags: euphemisms

During the Battle of the Bulge, when asked to surrender, US [General McAuliffe answered with the single word "Nuts!"](http://www.newsinhistory.com/blog/famous-wwii-battle-bulge-rallying-cry-%E2%80%98nuts%E2%80%99)

I know that "nuts" can be a crude way to refer to testicles ("He got hit in the nuts by the baseball") but I've always thought of the exclamation ("Aw, nuts!") as anodyne. Would a kid saying it in the 1940s have had his mouth washed out with soap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [EtymOnline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=nuts), by the 1950s "nuts" was taboo (or on its way):

> Connection with the slang "testicle" sense has tended to nudge it toward taboo. "On the N.B.C. network, it is forbidden to call any character a nut; you have to call him a screwball." ["New Yorker," Dec. 23, 1950] "Please eliminate the expression 'nuts to you' from Egbert's speech." [Request from the Hays Office regarding the script of "The Bank Dick," 1940] This desire for avoidance accounts for the euphemism *nerts* (c.1925).

By the 1940s, "nuts" was on its way out. In its place, the euphemism [*nerts*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nerts) was apparently created.

Comment: So, it's bad to call someone a nut but calling him a dick is just fine?

Comment: @Malvolio: It was [slang for detective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bank_Dick)

Comment: I knew that, I was just pointing out the irony.

Comment: @Malvolio: Sorry, sarcasm doesn't translate well via text. But you're right--EtymOnline says the word "dick" was pejorative in the late 1800s even.

Comment: Pejorative, and even in 1940, slang for "penis".

Comment: @malvolio But a word can have multiple meanings. Pejorative, but note solely so.

Comment: Censors, in general, are not exactly known for their consistency...